# Configure the keyboard for console in OSMC

Tags: keyboard, raspi-config, osmc

It seems there is no `raspi-config` in OSMC. So, how can I configure the keyboard layout for the console?  (In Kodi it was easy to find, but this doesn't affect the console.)

I couldn't find anything like this in "My OSMC".

Is it possible to install `raspi-config`?

Answer (score 2):

`raspi-config` is specifically for Raspbian, whence the name. Try [these instructions](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/osmc-rc-rpi-french-keyboard-support/1601/7) for setting up a keyboard layout for OSMC. It involves installing a few packages and reconfiguring one, all from the console.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It doesn't contain a directly usable recipe, so I wrote a more detailed answer below.
BTW, it's not `raspbian-config` nor `raspbmc-config`, so it's quite logical people expect to see this program on any Debian-based operating system for RasPi, including `OSMC`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the link provided by tlhIngan](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/osmc-rc-rpi-french-keyboard-support/1601/2), here is what I did (as root, `sudo -s`):

- `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Here I was able to select (in my case) `de_DE.UTF-8`. No substancial changes to the user experience up to this point.

- `apt-get install console-setup`

Here I was able to choose `Other` first, and then the classic German keyboard layout with dead keys for accent grave and acute.

[rant on]
Hey, English-speaking developers, do you have the slightest idea how *painful* it is work with a non-configured German keyboard?  Almost every non-letter character is on another place, and some are really important!  Thus, keyboard configuration is *extremely* important, expecially when `ssh` access is disfunctional!
[/rant off]

After this, there was no reaction from the `ö` key anymore.  Ok, there seems to be some change in effect, and it might help to reboot:

- `shutdown -r now`

After rebooting, everything now seems to be fine.

*Final remarks*:

- It seems to be important to *first* do the `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and then `apt-get install console-setup`.
- The interactive configuration triggered by this installation can be repeated by entering `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`